# R Markdown: Empty line between list items

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've encountered something in R Markdown, that is somewhat puzzling to me. When using ordered lists, I sometimes run into a case where no empty line is added between the list item. That happens after the second level of a list and going back to a first-level item. If the example below is "knitted" in Markdown, no empty line is added between the last subpoint of 2. and the 3. point.

```
1. This is a thing

2. This is another thing
    + This is some subpoint thing
    + This, too, is something

3. This thing should have an empty line above it. It does, when compiled as pdf, it doesn't in html.
```

I tried two spaces, \newline in various locations, but nothing worked correctly. I'm sure it's something easy that I just missed...

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a result of the CSS used in the default html output, where `margin-bottom` is set to 0 for sublists. You can override this using CSS e.g.:

```
<style>
ol ul {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>

1. This is a thing

2. This is another thing
    + This is some subpoint thing
    + This, too, is something

3. This thing should have an empty line above it. It does, when compiled as pdf, it doesn't in html
```

Comment: Great, that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to accomplish this if you'd like this to be applied to all unordered sub-lists.  The `>` symbol specifies that this style should be applied to `ul` elements which are direct children of `li` elements.

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
li > ul {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```
````

Comment: This question asks about ordered lists. Normally, the answers on SO are meant to be a direct response to the specific question.

Comment: Hmm I see your point!  Though, I'm pretty sure the sub-list which the author is asking about is actually an unordered list.  While I understand that it is a child of an ordered list, it's direct parent will be an <li> element either way.  Is that correct?

Thanks! :)